# Calculating the speed of a moving object based on its distance to a target

Tags: algorithm, kinematics

I am writing a simulation in which an object moves in a 2D world towards a target position, stored as vector `target(x,y)`. The object position is stored as position vector `pos(x,y)` as well. The object contains two more vectors, the desired movement velocity `dv(x,y)`, as well as the current movement velocity `cv(x,y)`. At the start of the simulation both these velocity vectors are initial, i.e. set to `(0,0)`.

When the object should move towards the target position, I calcuate the desired velocity vector `dv`, normalize it, and scale it by a movement speed value:

```
dv.set(target).sub(pos).normalize()
dv.scale(speed)
```

I want to make the movement look more realistic, that's why I use two velocity vectors. `dv` tells the full speed I want to move the object, and `cv` holds the real speed the object currently moves at.

Then at each frame (update step) the current velocity `cv` is set based on the desired velocity `dv` and an acceleration value `acc`. This is done by simply calculating the difference between `cv` and `dv` and clamping this difference to `acc`. That way the object starts to move slowly and accelerates gradually to eventually reach full speed.

So far this is working fine. Now I want to make use of `acc` for deceleration as well. When the distance between `pos` and `target` is at a certain value, the desired velocity `dv` should be set to `(0,0)`, so that the object gradually decelerates until it comes to a full stop at the target position.

My question is: How can I calculate at which distance I need to set `dv` to `(0,0)` (i.e. tell the system to stop movement), so that the object decelerates correctly to stop *exactly* at the target position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the kinematic equations:

### v<sub>f</sub><sup>2</sup> = v<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2 * a * d

- v<sub>f</sub> is your final velocity, or 0 (the speed you want to be going)
- v<sub>i</sub> is your initial velocity, given (the speed your object is currently moving).
- a is acceleration
- d is distance.

#### Solve for d:

- 2*a*d = v<sub>f</sub><sup>2</sup> - v<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>
- 2*a*d = 0 - v<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>

assume acceleration is negative, so multiply both sides by -1

- 2*|a|*d = v<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>

|a| is the absolute value of your acceleration (deceleration in your case)

- d = v<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> / (2*|a|)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I use `vi=10` and `a=0.5`, i.e. movement increases in steps of 0.5 until full speed is reached. With these values your last line gives me a distance of `d=100.0`, whereas from trial and error I know it should be a bit less than 1.0

Comment: I am adding `a` to the velocity vector at every single time step. So I assume your equation is based on `a` spreaded out over a whole second? Makes sense I guess. Is there an easy conversion of your solution to my situation?

Comment: @Matthias, if your acceleration is 0.5 m/s^2, and your timestep is 0.5, you'd only apply about 0.25 of that each timestep. Just divide your acceleration by your timestep amount. Your velocity should be similarly scaled, actually, so as to remain independent of the timestep (i.e. if you wanted to change your timestep to 10 for some reason, you don't want to magically see a 10x increase in velocity).

Comment: That makes much sense, thanks. So I was already scaling the velocity by the time step (which is a fraction of a second, i.e. `delta` since the last time step). Now I scale the acceleration by `delta` too. By applying your equation the deceleration works much better now. However the object stops a bit too early, it never fully reaches the target. I assume your equation is correct though and I need to search for the issue somewhere else...

Comment: Thank you very much, it works quite well now. Answer accepted :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a discrete time simulation of motion. One way to keep things simple is to perform the calculations in a way that makes acceleration and deceleration symmetrical. In other words, the distance traveled while accelerating should be the same as the distance traveled while decelerating.  As an example, assume

- acceleration is 5
- top speed is 13
- the object begins decelerating as soon as it reaches top speed

Here's how the discrete time simulation would progress

```
first tick
  old speed = 0
  new speed = 5
  distance  = 5

second tick
  old speed = 5
  new speed = 10
  distance  = 15

third tick
  old speed = 10
  new speed = 13
  distance  = 28  <-- total distance while accelerating

fourth tick
  old speed = 13
  distance  = 41
  new speed = 10  <-- not 8!!!

fifth tick
  old speed = 10
  distance  = 51
  new speed =  5

sixth tick
  old speed =  5
  distance  = 56  <-- Yay, twice the distance, we have symmetry
  new speed =  0
```

There are two key points here

- While accelerating the speed is updated first and then the distance is updated. While decelerating the order is reversed, the distance is updated first, and then the speed.
- When decelerating, it's important to keep the adjusted speed as a multiple of the acceleration

In the C programming language, the following code could be used to update the speed during deceleration

```
if ( old_speed % acceleration != 0 )                   // if speed is not a multiple of acceleration
   new_speed = old_speed - old_speed % acceleration;   //   reduce speed to a multiple of acceleration
else                                                   // otherwise
   new_speed = old_speed - acceleration;               //   reduce speed by acceleration
```

If acceleration and deceleration are symmetrical, then computing the deceleration distance is the same as computing the acceleration distance.

```
distance = acceleration * (1+2+3+ ... +N) + fudge_factor
```

where

- `N` is `top_speed / acceleration` truncated to an integer, e.g. `13/5 ==> 2`
- `fudge_factor` is `0` if top speed is a multiple of acceleration, or
  `top_speed` otherwise

The computation can be simplified by noting that

```
1+2+3+ ... +N = N * (N+1) / 2
```

In C, the total distance travelled while decelerating could be computed as follows

```
int top_speed = 13;
int acceleration = 5;

int N = top_speed / acceleration;     // Note: in C, integer division truncates

int fudge = 0;
if ( top_speed % acceleration != 0 )
    fudge = top_speed;

int distance = acceleration * (N * (N+1)) / 2 + fudge;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I use `top_speed=10.0` and `acceleration=0.5`, and with these values your last line `acceleration * (N * (N+1)) / 2 + fudge` gives me `distance=105.0`, whereas from trial and error I know it should be a bit less than 1.0